# Is it possible to view the amount of free space on a remote server without having to map it as a network drive?

Tags: mapped-drive

Currently, if a remote drive is mapped from a Windows client (by navigating to Computer/This PC and clicking "Map a Network Drive"), each time that the cursor is hovered over the newly-mapped drive its associated tooltip displays the amount of free space on the remote server. Is there any way to view free space of a remote server without having to explicitly map it as a network drive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159341/how-to-get-disk-capacity-and-free-space-of-remote-computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of articles on this, but the basic premise is

`get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername remotecomputer`

You can expand on this with syntax such as

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName remotecomputer -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" |
Select-Object Size,FreeSpace

$disk.Size
$disk.FreeSpace
```